# is the pronunciation of "아저씨"same as "아젓시"?

Tags: pronunciation

Is the pronunciation of "아저씨" same as "아젓시"? I know that the word 아젓시 does not exist but just curious about pronunciation.

Answer (score 3):

Since 아젓시 isn't a real word, it's impossible to know exactly, but we can look at similar words in the dictionary:

칫솔 (toothbrush) is listed with 2 pronunciations:[치쏠] and [칟쏠].  So the first one suggests that 아젓시 would indeed be pronounced like 아저씨, and the second one suggests a slightly different pronunciation.  Likewise, 귓속 (inside the ear) can be pronounced [귀쏙] or [귇쏙].

However, 맛소금 (salt + MSG) is listed with just one pronunciation: [맏쏘금].
Likewise, 덧신 (overshoes) is also listed with just one: [덛씬].

The difference between the first two and the latter two may be that the ㅅ in 칫솔 and 귓속 is a [사이시옷](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%82%AC%EC%9E%87%EC%86%8C%EB%A6%AC_%ED%98%84%EC%83%81#%EC%82%AC%EC%9D%B4%EC%8B%9C%EC%98%B7%EC%9D%98_%ED%91%9C%EA%B8%B0) which only appears when two words are joined, so it's easier for it to disappear, whereas in 맛소금 and 덧신, the ㅅ is found in the original words 맛 and 덧, so it doesn't disappear.

So if your word 아젓시 was based on the imaginary word 아젓+시, I think you'd have to pronounce it [아젇씨], but if it were based on the imaginary word 아저 + 사이시옷 + 시, maybe it would be possible to pronounce it 아저씨.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you speak very slowly, I think they sound the same.

Answer (score 1):

According to the standard, the pronunciation of last consonant must be among 7 consonants: ㄱ(k), ㄴ(n), ㄷ(t), ㄹ(l), ㅁ(m), ㅂ(p), ㅇ(ng). When ㅅ is at the end, as ㅅ's articulation point is the same to ㄷ, ㅅ changes into ㄷ.

Also, since ㅅ in 시 is in front of ㄷ, ㅅ becomes ㅆ.

So, the pronunciation of `아젓시` is `아젇씨`, which is different from `아저씨`.

Answer (score 1):

In Korean, there are five fortis (된소리) 'ㄲ', 'ㄸ', 'ㅃ', 'ㅆ',
'ㅉ'

> **된소리 법칙(law) :** Sound between two vowels
>
> **Example :** 소쩍새 (scops owl) -> 솢쩍쌔, 어깨 (shoulder)-> 억깨,
> 오빠 (brother)->옵빠, 으뜸 (best) -> 읃뜸

**Irregular :** 깨끗하다 (clean) -> 깨끗타다

Here, if we follow law, then 깩끗타다. But by ㄲ of 깨, we have
깨끗타다.